# Gem installation hangs when using Alpine Ruby image in Docker

Tags: ruby, docker

I have a simple Dockerfile where I'm looking to switch from the regular Ruby image to the Alpine one but doing so causes the installation of the Bundler gem to hang.

When using the regular Ruby image my image builds succesfully:

```
FROM ruby:2.2
ENV BUNDLER_VERSION 1.17.3
RUN gem install bundler -v ${BUNDLER_VERSION}
```

```
Building gem
Step 1/3 : FROM ruby:2.2
 ---> 6c8e6f9667b2
Step 2/3 : ENV BUNDLER_VERSION 1.17.3
 ---> Running in 0cc44e086669
Removing intermediate container 0cc44e086669
 ---> 7ec42cea5037
Step 3/3 : RUN gem install bundler -v ${BUNDLER_VERSION}
 ---> Running in e9607bc2995a
Successfully installed bundler-1.17.3
1 gem installed
Removing intermediate container e9607bc2995a
 ---> 52790fc5c2a5
Successfully built 52790fc5c2a5
```

However, if I try to switch to Alpine the gem installation hangs indefinitely:

```
FROM ruby:2.2-alpine
ENV BUNDLER_VERSION 1.17.3
RUN gem install bundler -v ${BUNDLER_VERSION}
```

```
Building gem
Step 1/3 : FROM ruby:2.2-alpine
 ---> d212148e08f7
Step 2/3 : ENV BUNDLER_VERSION 1.17.3
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 92f44eed070c
Step 3/3 : RUN gem install bundler -v ${BUNDLER_VERSION}
 ---> Running in fb834649b9cc
```

Any ideas on what I could look at to begin troubleshooting this?

Comment: Alpine doesn't come with gcc by default, which most gems with native extensions need. Either add the APK for gcc, or build your gems outside the container.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs thanks, I suspect that you're right. I'm surprised about a lack of status/error messaging during the install... If you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it.